# $G$ is an abelian group, $H \triangleleft G$, show that $G/H$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove: if H is a normal subgroup of an abelian group G then G/H is abelian.

Here is what I've tried:

We must show that G/H is abelian. Let a and b be two elements of G/H.

Is this a poor way to start the proof?

Comment: Any subgroup of an *Abelian* group $G$ is normal. But yes, a reasonable way to show that the quotient group is normal is tp start with two elements and show they commute.

Comment: You may want to let the two elements in G/H be aH and bH, where a, b are in G

Answer (score 4):

$(aH)(bH) = (ab)H = (ba)H = (bH)(aH)$. Done.